Alibaba-rsocket-broker Cyclic dependency during bean initialisation
I have an issue that I am not sure how to fix with Alibaba Rsocket Broker v1.1.6
It looks as if injecting an Rsocket client created through the RSocketRemoteServiceBuilder in a service created with @RSocketService is not working. This means that the server cannot call other microservices for data using Rsocket clients.
Code example adapted from the Alibaba Rsocket Broker spring boot example:
Service:
@RSocketService(serviceInterface = Rx3UserService.class)
@Service
public class Rx3UserServiceImpl implements Rx3UserService {
     
     @Autowired private AccountService accountService;

     ...implementation
}

Clients:
    @Bean
    public Rx3UserService rx3UserService(UpstreamManager upstreamManager) {
        return RSocketRemoteServiceBuilder
                .client(Rx3UserService.class)
                .upstreamManager(upstreamManager) //setting this will cause a cyclic dependency
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public AccountService accountService(UpstreamManager upstreamManager) {
        return RSocketRemoteServiceBuilder
                .client(AccountService.class)
                .encodingType(RSocketMimeType.Protobuf)
                .upstreamManager(upstreamManager) //setting this will cause a cyclic dependency
                .build();
    }

When injecting the AccountService client into the Rx3UserServiceImpl service I get a cyclic dependency error as the Upstream manager cannot be injected into the AccountService due to:
Bean is under creation error.
The issues seems to come from the fact that the RSocketAutoConfiguration class has an init method on the upstreamManager bean as follows:
  @Bean(
        initMethod = "init"
    )
    public UpstreamManager rsocketUpstreamManager(@Autowired RSocketRequesterSupport rsocketRequesterSupport) throws JwtTokenNotFoundException {
        ...implementation
}

The SmartLifecycleUpstreamManagerImpl's init method reaches the UpstreamCluster#init method which, at line 138, calls:
this.loadBalancedRSocket = new LoadBalancedRSocket(this.getServiceId(), this.urisProcessor, this.rsocketRequesterSupport);  

The LoadBalancedRSocket does this at line 102:
if (!requesterSupport.exposedServices().get().isEmpty()) {
            this.isServiceProvider = true;
}

The exposedServices().get() method queries the application context for the @RSocketService annotated beans which have as dependency the AccountService with the upstreamManager as the dependency resulting in a cyclic dependency failure.
Am I missing something or perhaps I misconfigured something? Did anybody else run into the same issue?
I am trying to call an rsocket endpoint from an rsocketservice. I simply want to fetch some data from another service while processing an rsocket request.
EDIT: I know this works if i lazily inject the dependency in the Rx3UserServiceImpl to fix the cyclic dependency, however this is more a quick hacky solution than a proper way of doing things.
